# How to concatenate strings in JavaScript with tabs and carriage returns in Geany?

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation, stringstream, geany

I'm making an app with dynamic content loader, it's load the content via ajax then change the DOM. I have a structure/schema, my question is how can I to concatenate the strings, I want to keep my code "indentated" for make it easly readable...

Example:
[image]

How can I achieve that? I need some special scape character or sort of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the newline character at the end of each line with a `\`, though it's generally considered bad practice (because it's very easy to miss an escape in maintaining the code.)

```
var page = '\
  <div class="row well">\
    <div class="row info-block">\
      <div class="col-xs-4 logo-container">\
        ' + logo + '\
      </div>\
    </div>\
  </div>';
```

What you really want is ES6 template strings, though:

```
var page = `
  <div class="row well">
    <div class="row info-block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 logo-container">
        ${logo}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
```

[Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) allow multiline strings by default and support interpolation (the `${logo}` above.)

Note: there is a difference between the two resulting strings.  In the newline-escaped string, the newlines are actually not a part of the resulting string; whereas, they are in the template string example.

Comment: Nice, but I have a question, ES6 is compatible with mobile devices? Including some relatively old devices?

Comment: @alessadro, unfortunately template strings are not well supported yet on mobile: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#template_strings.

Comment: Oh, well, I will use the escape solution for the moment, thanks for your help/time :-)